# Is it possible that browser cache an image and does not make the request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, caching, browser

I am using react to render a simple `<img>` tag. When I unmount and mount (the image is actually removed from the dom and re-rendered) the image often I can see the image but if I see the devtools "network" tab I cannot see any kind of request being made by the browser. (And the server does not receive anything so the request is actually not made).

How is this possible? Usually when the browser use cache you see the request and get a "from the disk" or a 304 from the server, in this case, the request is not made.

My server is sending Cache-Control: 'no-cache' with an etag because I need the browser to check with the server any time.

Is this possible?

Here an example, if you open the tag network and press on "hide" you can see requests are not being made. how can I avoid this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/lj5mm7rjm

Comment: I also don't see new requests if I add and remove an image in vanilla JS, maybe browsers are smart enough to see that it's the same image...

Comment: @LucaKiebel How can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't know, why would you want to avoid this? It seems like smart behavior. If you don't want the browser to cache things, you can send the appropriate headers for that.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I am seding Cache-Control: no-cache because I want the browser to ask the server anytime, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: My guess is the browser has already loaded it into memory. If you refresh the page that is generally where you'll see the request made to the disk instead of to the server if the image has been cached. Your browser is smart enough to know that the image path is the same and can just serve it from memory.

Comment: @Adam and this is ok, but I can avoid it? This way I cannot use etags properly

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to to suppress this behavior is to add a time parameter like:

```js
render() {
    const time = new Date().getTime();
    const url = `http://iserotope.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hi.jpg?t=${time}`;
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {!this.state.hide && (
          <img
            width="100"
            src={url}
          />
        )}

        <h2 onClick={this.toggle}>hide</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: But this way I cannot use etags to get 304 responses from server

Comment: I think you are looking for `must-revalidate` on your cache-control header. But i'm not sure what will be happen on your situation.